# How can I pass query string parameters to VSTO ClickOnce application?

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce

I've been working on an Outlook VSTO AddIn using VS 2015.  I noticed that the publish options are different for the VSTO ClickOnce deployment than they are for a regular application deployed via ClickOnce.  Specifically, I need to be able to allow URL parameters to be passed to the application, and this option is not available in the VSTO publish options.

I have tried using MageUI to enable URL parameters to be passed, but it always results in me getting computed hash errors, even if I set the MageUI preferences to use SHA256 (which is what the signing certificate uses).

If I just publish with VS 2015 and avoid using MageUI, the deployment can be installed, but obviously it doesn't receive any query string parameters from the deployment URL.

I'm at my wits' end on this, and I could really use some help.  I've spent days searching Google and SO specifically, but I haven't found any solutions that address the problem of getting URL parameters passed to the ClickOnce deployed VSTO.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this article on [How to pass arguments to an offline ClickOnce application](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/) .

You can pass parameters to an application using query parameters:

- `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(shortcutPath, argsToPass);`

This is how you read the argument string:

- `//Get the ActivationArguments from the SetupInformation property of the domain.
  string[] activationData = 
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;`

Comment: Posting link is not useful. What is the content gets removed/moved? Answer should provide all necessary information.